# Why is php.net blocked when I try to view it in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, virus-scanning

I tried to view:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

And Google Chrome threw out:

Warning - visiting this web site may harm your computer!

Suggestions:
Return to the previous page and pick another result.
Try another search to find what you're looking for.
Or you can continue to http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php at your own risk. For detailed information about the problems we found, visit Google's Safe Browsing diagnostic page for this site.

For more information about how to protect yourself from harmful software online, you can visit StopBadware.org.

If you are the owner of this web site, you can request a review of your site using Google's Webmaster Tools. More information about the review process is available in Google's Webmaster Help Center.
Advisory provided by    Google

This doesn't make sense. This is php.net...

EDIT: This is a not a resourceful question anymore. (1.11.2013.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2013/10/24/php-net-blocked-by-google-false-positive-or-not.html) to be insightful as to why the site has been blocked.

> "Of the 1513 pages we tested on the site over the past 90 days, 4 page(s) resulted in malicious 
>      software being downloaded and installed without user consent."
>
> Rasmus Lerdorf – the creator of PHP – is currently trying to get Google to stop blocking the
>      whole php.net website after it was suspected of containing malware. In a tweet earlier this 
>      morning, Rasmus posted a screenshot and suggested that the block was caused by a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Chrome extension "Adblock Plus" causes a blank page fro php.net

- Disable or remove the extension
- Clear Google Chrome history
- Restart the browser

This will solve the problem temporarily

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same thing... looks like either php.net was hacked or Google blacklisted them for some reason. I would wait a couple of days then check back.